# How to define the displayed data?

Tags: c#, c

A new satellite data processing center has just been completed and ready for the initial testing using live data being sent down from an orbiting satellite.  As the very first messages are displayed on the screen and you notice many of the data values are wildly out of range.
    For example, on the terminal screen is something defined as “delta time” and it seems to be out of the expected range [0.01 to 10,000.00 seconds], but the value displayed (as a double)  is [2.44049168e-153 seconds].  After further investigation into the raw byte-based data stream, you find the original data being sent down from the satellite for this double word as [0x3C 0x4E 0xD1 0x91 0x5C 0x5E 0x20 0x40].  On one of the old terminals, this data is displayed correctly and is within the expected range. 
What caused this problem? 
If this is the real problem, what should the actual value be?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  While you can get help with homework assignments, in a manner of speaking, this is definitely not the way to go about it.  Here's a starter guide on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is because of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

The `double` representation of the array of bytes can be shown as

```
8.18430000000000035243
```

and in the reverse sequence is

```
0.00000000000000000334
```